# convert decimal to ascii in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, decimal

i have many records in my table which are like

```
&#1076;&#1103;&#1076;&#1100;&#1082;&#1086;
kurba&#287;a
d&#279;d&#279;
```

Those are all words and i want them to convert into normal words in javascript.
Is there any javascrtipt method for this?

Comment: Can you give a little more context here. What is the encoding you are using?

Comment: `s = document.createElement('span'); s.innerHTML = '&#1076;&#1103;&#1076;&#1100;&#1082;&#1086;'; console.log(s.innerText)` will return this: `"дядько"`

Comment: In case you miss it while going through the answers to the linked question, HTML characters are Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are HTML entities, an alternative could be created temporarily an element and then get the innerText.

```js
var textNode = document.createElement("span");
textNode.innerHTML = `&#1076;&#1103;&#1076;&#1100;&#1082;&#1086;
kurba&#287;a
d&#279;d&#279;`

console.log(textNode.innerText);
```